# Polynom equality modulo p

Tags: polynomials

I found these two equations:

(a) $$X^4 + 1 \equiv (X + 1)^4 \mod \ 2$$ 
(b) $$X^4 + 1 \equiv (X^2 - X - 1)(X^2 + X - 1) \mod \ 3$$

I would like to understand the concept of modulo for Polynoms.

How were they made? And how to verify these equality ?

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\;2k=0\pmod 2\;,\;\;\forall\,k\in\Bbb Z\;$ , and thus

$$(x+1)^4=x^4+\overbrace{4x^3+6x^2+4x}^{=0\pmod 2}+1=x^4+1\pmod 2$$

Try now something similar with the other case

Comment: as I am neophyte, why 4x^3 +6x^2 + 4x = 0 (mod2) ?

does it means 0x^3 + 0x^2+ 4x = 0 (mod 2) - where 4 and 6 are replace by 0 as it is mod 2?

Comment: @ronan each coefficient is taken modulo $2$, and $4$ and $6$ are $0$ modulo $2$.

Comment: @ronan Yes, exactly. Also read quid's comment.

Comment: @ronan I have elaborated on that point in my answer. Please feel welcome to ask questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It seems  your question is: how does integer congruence arithmetic ("modular" arithmetic) extend to polynomials? Simply because the [proofs of the basic congruence laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (sum and product rules) work universally (technically: they use only basic ring laws (distributive,commutative,associative), so the proofs remain valid in any commutative ring). This universality becomes clearer when one studies abstract algebra, which studies more structural versions of these ideas (ideals & quotient rings, a.k.a. residue rings).

In particular $\ f\equiv g\pmod m\ $ means that $\,m\mid f-g\,$ i.e. $\,(f-g)/m\in \Bbb Z[x],\,$ i.e. it is a polynomial with *integer* coefficients. Let's look at the proof of the product rule

$\bf{Congruence\ Product\ Rule}\rm\ \ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{F\equiv f},\ \ and \ \  \color{#0a0}{G\equiv g}\ \Rightarrow\ \color{blue}{FG\equiv fg}\ \ \ (mod\ m)$

$\bf{Proof}\rm\ \ \ m\mid \color{#c00}{F\!-\!f},\ \color{#0a0}{G\!-\!g}\ \Rightarrow\ m\mid (\color{#c00}{F\!-\!f})\ G + f\ (\color{#0a0}{G\!-\!g})\ =\ \color{blue}{FG - fg}\quad $ **QED**

This is the same as the proof for integers, except that we are working with polynomials. The proof works in both cases because it uses only basic (ring) arithmetic laws (distributive,commutative, associative), which hold true both for integers $\,\Bbb Z\,$ and polynomials $\,\Bbb Z[x],\,$ since both are commutative rings.

In particular, when computing mod $m$ the Product Rule yields $\,i\equiv j\,\Rightarrow\, i x^k\equiv j x^k.\,$ So we can replace all coefficients by their remainder mod $m$, i.e. we can mod out coefficients.  Doing that in both of your examples quickly yields the sought congruences.

**Remark** $\ $ Informally (in rings) working "mod m" means adjoining the hypothesis $\,m = 0$ to the ambient (ring) axioms. Applying the ring axioms then yields inferences that  other elements $= 0,\,$ e.g.  if $\,m = 0 = m'\,$ that $\,am+b m' = 0\,$ for all $\,a,b\,$ in the ring. The algebraic *structure* underlying these matters will become clearer when one studies *ideals* of rings.

Answer (score 0):

It just results from the  fact that  in a (commutative) ring of characteristic $2$ (i.e. a ring $R$ for which $2\cdot 1_R=0_R$) the map $x \mapsto x^2$ is a ring homomorphism (called the Frobenius morphism): for all $x,y\in R$
$$(xy)^2=x^2y^2,\quad (x+y)^2=x^2+y^².$$
The last equality results from the binomial formula, noting that $2xy=0$ since   the characteristic is $2$.
Now an equality between polynomials modulo $2$ means we're looking at polynomials with coefficients in the field $\mathbf F_2=\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, which is of characteristic $2$.

By a trivial induction, we also have $$(x+y)^{2^n}=x^{2^n}+ y^{2^n}.$$

Answer (score -1):

For $(a),$

$y^{m+1}-y=y(y^m-1)$ is divisible by $y(y-1)$ which being the product of two consecutive integers is even

$\implies y^{m+1}\equiv y\pmod2$ for $m\ge1$

$\implies y^4\equiv y\pmod2$ set $y=X, X+1$

For $(b),$

$(x^2-1-x)(x^2-1-x)=(x^2-1)^2-x^2=x^4-3x^2+1\equiv x^4+1\pmod3$

Comment: No need to ask why you got a downvote. A last time you did, I explained it, and you did not react.

Comment: I am new with this website - I am unable to click on upper arrow as it requires me to have a reputation above 15.
sorry if I made a mistake.
this explaination helps me too. Thanks!

Comment: @ronan you should be aware that the fact that two polynomials take the same values modulo $2$ does not mean that they are equal. In particular $X^4 \not \equiv X \mod 2$ when you are dealing with *polynomials.*

Comment: @quid, $X^4-X=X(X^3-1)$ which is divisible by $X(X-1)$ which is even, right?

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what $X$ is. If it is and integer, then it is true. If it is however an indeterminate in  in a polynomial then it false/makes no sense. The question mentions polynomials. Generally, it is not true that two polynomials modulo $2$ are the same when they induce the same map from $Z/2$ to $Z/2$. One thus cannot argue as you do to ascertain the equality of the *polynomials*, only of the induced maps.

Comment: @quid, How about the validity of the accepted answer if $X$ is not an integer?

Comment: It is valid. The argument is that each *coefficient* (in the part that vanishes) is $0 \mod 2$, and $0 \cdot X^n = 0$. See the comments there.