# Mathematical development with Polynom modulo n

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I have to implement a method seen in an article, and I'm stuck with some mathematical development. The article is on iEEE Xplore, so I'll try to be as specific as I can.

It's about [pairing-based cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography), and the global idea is to

1. Create a MasterKey
2. Build $n$ shares of this MasterKey
3. Reconstruct the MasterKey based on at least $t$ shared received ($t<n$)

Of course these 3 steps are done on differents systems (clients/trusted parties/server), but the goal is to discuss the mathematical concepts.

---

To achieve this, the author of the paper uses modular arithmetic. Here are the operations done at each step :

#### Create MasterKey

- for $0\leq i<t$ choose $r_i\in _R\mathbb{Z}_q$
- set MasterKey $MK = r_0$

#### Build the shares

- Compute $n$ shares $s_i =R(i) \in \mathbb{Z}_q$, with

$$R(x) = r_0 + r_1 x + r_2 x^2 + \dots + r_{t-1} x^{t-1}~(\bmod~ q)\qquad (1)$$

#### Re-build the Masterkey

- Compute $ MK = \sum_{i=1}^t \lambda_{0, j}~s_i = s$ with $$ \lambda_{x, j}= \prod_{\substack{i\neq i\\j=1}}^t \frac{x-i}{j-i}~(\bmod~ q) \qquad (2)$$

**The problem is at this step.** I've tried to develop the reconstruction of the masterKey (with a small $t$ and $n$), but I haven't found anything.

---

#### TL;DR

Given $(1)$ and $(2)$; how can we prove that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^t \lambda_{0, j}~s_i = s = r_0 \qquad (3) $$

Could someone help me develop the construction operations ? I tried using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1117609/339268) in $(2)$ but I didn't go realy far...